# Issue converting single site to multi-site - blogs.dir folder not created

Tags: multisite, installation, migration

I have an existing WP install that I'm attempting to convert into a multi-site, in order to set up a development version in a subdirectory (required for testing an SSL on the same domain).

I've been able to do the initial stages of the multi-site okay, but when I've inspected my directory for the blogs.dir directory, I found that instead of a folder, there's a text file there.

Here's a screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/jlV4JAaUUmV

I can't find any examples of this happening online, nor am I sure how the install works okay without a folder there.

All parts of the original site run fine, but because the blogs.dir is a text file, I can't import files for my development installation...

Is there a step that I missed?

Comment: Check through an [FTP client](https://filezilla-project.org/) if the directory is really a text file. Probably the file editor showing wrong icon? Can you browse through it?

Comment: not related to the question, IMHO you are doing it wrong. a network sub site is not a valid development enviroment for anything that needs to be used on the same network. In this setting there is no real segregation between development and production code.

Comment: Have checked in two FTP clients, clicking on the blogs.dir results in it trying to download the file.

Comment: @MarkKaplun fair call, I haven't done this type of set up before. It's largely for testing the SSL.

Comment: @Ashkas, why not to set a full wordpress install at the subdirectory?

Comment: @MarkKaplun That was the other approach I was deciding between, but I thought multi-site might have been the more 'usual' approach. Appears not. Think I'll give a single install into a sub-directory a go.

Answer (score 3):

blogs.dir isn't used for multisites created after WordPress 3.5. Instead everything exists in wp-content/uploads.